# ASP.NET ReportViewer with Forms Authentication

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, reportviewer

We currently have a reporting server that uses Windows Authentication, and this works fine,

The problem is that the web application we are using, uses forms authentication.

When we connect the Report Viewer control to the service, we have tried this, which works:

```
Public Class ReportViewerCredentials
    Implements IReportServerCredentials
    Private _userName As String
    Private _password As String
    Private _domain As String


    Public Sub New(ByVal userName As String, ByVal password As String, ByVal domain As String)
        _userName = userName
        _password = password
        _domain = domain
    End Sub


    Public ReadOnly Property ImpersonationUser() As System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity Implements Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.IReportServerCredentials.ImpersonationUser
        Get
            Return Nothing
        End Get
    End Property


    Public ReadOnly Property NetworkCredentials() As System.Net.ICredentials Implements Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.IReportServerCredentials.NetworkCredentials
        Get
            Return New Net.NetworkCredential(_userName, _password, _domain)
        End Get
    End Property


    Public Function GetFormsCredentials(ByRef authCookie As System.Net.Cookie, ByRef userName As String, ByRef password As String, ByRef authority As String) As Boolean Implements Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.IReportServerCredentials.GetFormsCredentials
        userName = _userName
        password = _password
        authority = _domain
        Return Nothing
    End Function


End Class
```

And we set the authentication using this:

```
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = New ReportViewerCredentials("username", "password", "")
```

Now this is the only example we have found, and we don't really want to store the password when the user logs into the app, in order to send it using the following example.

Is there any way of using the forms authentication ticket to get access? Or any recommended way of doing this?

Note that we cannot change the authentication of the actual report service.

Thanks

Comment: did u check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12731078/windows-authentication-with-ssrs-asp-net-reportviewer-and-web-service

Comment: and https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/810572/how-to-configure-an-asp-net-application-for-a-delegation-scenario